# Re-Designing API to reject duplicate requests

Tags: java, web-services, api, api-design

I have an API exposed to certain parties of interest.There is this issue that sometimes they erroneously send multiple (identical )requests in a very short span of time i.e even before a response has been sent to the first request. Since, the servers handling these requests are load balanced there is no way that I am able to detect duplicate requests across servers. I am considering using a common cache across servers to store requests.Is there a specific design pattern that I can use for this issue ?

Comment: What type of request are they resending? POSTs to create resources? Do you have a single database, or are they clustered also? You could possibly use a conditional header like If-None-Match to address the issue.

Comment: They are post requests which trigger a lot of processing on my server.

Comment: Well, if your system is fully load balanced, then you need to add a single gatekeeper somewhere .. may as well be a cache in front. I'm not sure what you're looking for by way of design pattern. Get a request, cache it, and fire it forward. Ignore later requests to that particular URL/request body pair for as long as your business logic dictates.

Answer (score 1):

You could use redis, which is a distributed cache that is simple to use. http://redis.io/

You can add key value pairs to the RAM based database, and you can set a time limit on when they should be expired.  The cache does not persist to the harddisk though.

Comment: Thanks , Yes this looks like a good option, But I wanted to know if there is a standard design pattern in APIs to address this issue.